# Нужно ли здесь тире? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Из 17 проверенных павильонов – 7 заняли землю самовольно.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не требуется тире, и только если осерчавшему автору нужно обратить внимание читателя на вопиюще большую цифру, можно найти ему обоснование. Тогда тире можно трактовать как замещение подразумеваемого "целых" (хотя проще прямо так и написать; ещё можно "аж") или восклицания "подумать только!" - с тире вместо столь эмоциональных оценок предложение выглядит более строго, формально.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен.

**Наличие тире  зависит от текста,** например: «Предполагается, что многие павильоны построены незаконно: по крайней мере, из  семн**а**дцати проверенных павильонов ― семь заняли землю самовольно».

Здесь **авторское тире делит предложение на две части**, подчеркивая численное соотношение законных и незаконных объектов.

Но: «Проверка показала, что из 17 проверенных павильонов 7 заняли землю самовольно» (**нет паузы и тире**).

Comment: Вот в первом вашем примере тире совершенно не нужно, ибо два тире как будто обосабливают то, что лежит между ними. Неужели не чувствуете?

Comment: Спасибо, я планировала поставить двоеточие, потом решила заменить его тире и уже не заметила, что их получилось два.

Comment: >> *по крайней мере, из семнАдцати проверенных павильонов ― семь заняли землю самовольно.*   ...из семнадцати павильонов по **меньшей** мере семь заняли землю незаконно.

Answer (score 0):

> *Из 17 проверенных павильонов – 7 заняли землю самовольно.*
>
> Нужно ли здесь тире?

Рассматриваемое предложение, написанное без тире,  допускает возможность двоякого его прочтения.

См.:

*Из 17 проверенных павильонов // 7 заняли землю самовольно.*

*Из 17 проверенных // павильонов  7 заняли землю самовольно.*

**Чтобы исключить неопределённость, тире лучше поставить.**

Comment: Семь — не та величина. Такую неопределённость (меной мест) выражают обычно круглым числом. Да и слово «проверенных» не даёт повода округлять.

Comment: _shampar: Семь — не та величина. Такую неопределённость (меной мест) выражают обычно круглым числом._ === Не знаю, почему Вы так решили... См. примеры: _Таких молодцов, которых я, выражаясь на студенческом языке, гоняю или проваливаю, у меня ежегодно набирается **человек семь**_ (Чехов). === _Таковы были Перикл, Кимон, и еще немногие, **человек семь**_ (Василий Розанов)... И т. д. и т. п.

Comment: Я говорю, что  ОБЫЧНО так бывает. А ещё я говорю про переменную величину при проверке. Неточный результат проверку превращает в профанацию.